# Apache CXF - HTTP response '404: null' Exception

Tags: json, apache-camel, cxf

Im trying to pull data from a web service using Apache camel.  But for the same API, I get a correct JSON response as well as exception for different filtering conditions.

Ex:

http://student.com/rest/student-id/44

here 44 is a valid student-Id

will give me the corect JSON response and No CXF exception

But when i hit with an invalid student id, say '1n23',
the webserivce will return a proper error JSON

```
{
  "error": "No record found."
}
```

But in camel I get this exception

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '404: null' when communicating with http://student.com/rest/student-id/1n23
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1581) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:1155) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:428) [cxf-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:353) [cxf-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

This is my camel route

```
<route streamCache="true" id="StudentService">
            <from uri="servlet:{{student.service.url.relative}}" />             
            <to uri="bean:RequestProcessor?method=buildReq" />
            <to uri="log:camelRouteLogger?showHeaders=true" />
            <recipientList>
                <simple>cxf://?dataFormat=MESSAGE&amp;loggingFeatureEnabled=true</simple>
            </recipientList>                
            <to uri="log:camelRouteLogger?showHeaders=true" />
        </route>
```

RequestProcesor

```
public void buildReq(final Exchange exchange) {
        try {
            final HttpMessage httpMessage = exchange.getIn(HttpMessage.class);              
            String serviceUrl = StudentUrlWithStudentCode;              
            exchange.setOut(new DefaultMessage());
            final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(Message.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD, "GET");
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Client.REQUEST_CONTEXT, map);
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.DESTINATION_OVERRIDE_URL, serviceUrl);
            exchange.getOut().setHeader("API-KEY", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            exchange.getOut().setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            exchange.getOut().setBody("-");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**Edit**
I have added the following in route

```
<onException>
  <exception>org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException</exception>
  <handled>
     <constant>true</constant>
  </handled>                
  <bean ref="stdErrorHandler" method="errorHandler"/>       
</onException>
```

In StdErrorHandler

```
public void errorHandler(final Exchange exchange, @Body String payload ){
            System.out.println(payload);        
    }
```

Here I will receive only the dummy body that I have set in

```
exchange.getOut().setBody("Dummy Body");
```

How will I get the response payload.

Comment: Pasting that url in a brower gives the same error namely 404 not found. http://student.com/rest/student-id/1n23 You sure the url is correct?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti  its just a sample url. Yes the url is coorect, i get correct response for valid ids, but for invalid ids i dont even get the error json from the service.

Comment: I mean can you provide the url which should give the json error response? The one in your post does not do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the service which i am calling requires a key and i am sorry that i cannot give you the key. I believe its no the remote service which is causing the problem, because if i hit it from a rest client i'm getting the response. both error and valid data

Comment: The response code 404 of the server raises an exception at client side. This is the expected behaviour. You can use `onException(Exception.class).` to catch the exception. See http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

Comment: @pedrofb Thanks, The response code is 404. How wilI get the original error json from the response inside exception handler

Comment: See samples at documentation. I think you can use  `<onException><exception>...</exception><bean> ref="yourService" method="serviceFailed" />` and define a method `serviceFailed` in the bean with  `@Body` annotation. The payload should be the received json

Comment: @pedrofb  Now Im getting the dummy body which i have set, not the response Json.

Comment: In the onException you get the exception that camel/cxf makes, not the actual response body. Anyone knows how to tell camel/cxf to not translate an error response to some default exception?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTTPConduit I found following comment:

> ```
>         // "org.apache.cxf.transport.no_io_exceptions" property should be set in case the exceptions
>         // should not be handled here; for example jax rs uses this
>
>         // "org.apache.cxf.transport.process_fault_on_http_400" property should be set in case a
>         // soap fault because of a HTTP 400 should be returned back to the client (SOAP 1.2 spec)
> ```